Ubuntu 20.04 and UHD graphics Intel N100 processor
I have a mini-pc that has the Intel N100 processor. My graphics application (rviz - ROS Noetic) is very slow. The output of the glxinfo command is saying that Linux is using llvmpipe instead of using the processor's graphics hardware.
#glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)

#inxi -G
Graphics:  
    Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
    Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1366x768~76Hz 
    OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6

#uname -r
5.15.0-107-generic

I did a test and installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4 LTS on the same mini-pc and the glxinfo command output shows:
#glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-N)

#inxi -G

Graphics:
   Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: Kernel
   Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.22.1.1 with Xwayland v: 22.1.1
     compositor gnome-shell v: 42.9 driver: gpu i 915 resolution 1360x768~60Hz
   OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL-N)
     v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2

 #uname -r
 6.5.0-35-generic

The problem is that ROS Noetic only works on ubuntu 20.04. Is there any way to install the correct video driver in Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.6 LTS?

You mention releases, but give no clues as to product (Server? Desktop?) and what I'm really wondering is which kernel stack you've opted to use (LTS releases have choice! with default set by install media - thus server/desktop issue).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using GA stack is using the same kernel as 20.04 LTS using HWE for example... but you've given no clues as to what you're using, NOR what you found works on 22.04

I added some information you mentioned, if you need more please let me know

FYI: If you tested Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04 (or .1) media then you'd be using the 5.15 kernel that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses when using HWE.. but Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Desktop using HWE will use the 6.5 kernel from Ubuntu 23.10 which is a far newer release, or kernel modules not packaged by Ubuntu for the older 20.04 release. I don't know if 3rd party sources have packaged it for the older release sorry.

these intel links helped me solve the problem:
https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal-arc.html
https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.html
